# A pandas column of float turns out to be object?

Tags: python, object, merge

Basically, I would like to do this

```
pd.merge(Investments1,Investments2, how = "outer", left_on = left_key, right_on = right_key)
```

Error is

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

So I check type of right_on:

```
Investments2['SECURITY CODE']
Name: SECURITY CODE, dtype: float64.
```

But what happen to left_on is:

```
Investments2['security code']
Out[104]: 
116     11111
118    222222
119    333333
Name: security code, dtype: object

type(Investments2.iloc[1,1])
Out[106]: float
```

Is it the case that a column of floats turns out to be an object while an object means a string?

Comment: I think there are some typos. Left side should be Investment1 with 'SECURITY CODE' in it while right side should be Investment2 with 'security code' in it.

Answer (score 2):

Transform `Investments2` before you merge. Like,

```
Investments2['security code'] = Investments2['security code'].transform(float)
```

*or* as pointed out in the comments, use [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype)

```
Investments2['security code'] = Investments2['security code'].astype(float)
```

Comment: which is better, `transform` or `astype(float)`?

Comment: @VanPeer Better invites subjective opinion; working code is always better. Beyond that is a topic for codereview

Comment: ya, right. just checked and found that `astype(float)` is far better when it comes to performance compared to `transform`

Comment: Thanks. I used the former to handle it. But what is the underlying logic for a column of floats to be a string here? Thanks for explanations.